# method is not defined - how compiler missed it?

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, compiler-construction, error-handling

Any clues why the method in my class compiles and says that it was not declared when after I try to run it? As anyone can see in the code, the function2 is declared in the class:

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self):
      pass

  def function2(self,myfilename):
      file = open(myfilename, "r")

      for line in file:
          print(line, end='')

      file.close()

  def function1(self,myfilename):
      function2(myfilename)

def main():
    myfilename = "input.txt"    
    obj = MyClass()
    obj.function1(myfilename) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I compile the code with no problem. But when trying run, it says:

```
NameError: name 'function2' is not defined
```

Why this compiles nicely, but though get crashed when put to run? Any suggestions?

Comment: What compiler? How are you compiling python?

Comment: @mushroom - running on python3 with Geany: python3 -m py_compile "test.py"

Comment: What is your reason for using py_compile? Just so you know, you don't have to compile your python code before running it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the following -

```
  def function1(self,myfilename):
      function2(myfilename)
```

with -

```
  def function1(self,myfilename):
      self.function2(myfilename)
```

Comment: I am trying. But the SO said that I have to wait at least 4 minutes to accept it.